# SNMP and SQL Server, is it possible to store the alerts in sql server without using any program?

Tags: snmp, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an old system (a legacy system) that reads SNMP messages and stores (**somehow**) them into a SQL server 2008 tables (or 2008r2). The system is working, however, I am clueless about how it stores into a SQL server table.

Is it possible to read the SNMP and store it into a table of SQL without a program or SNMP must use a program or service to store the information?

Answer (score 2):

SNMP is a protocol. Your legacy system is polling or receiving SNMP from what it's monitoring, and then storing that in SQL. The monitoring system *is* a program, it doesn't need an additional program to speak to SQL. It's probably got an ODBC or other connection to the database. Check the legacy system for existing ODBC connections. If it doesn't have any (and they might be for the service account running the monitoring system so you wouldn't see them if you were logged in as yourself), then it might have the SQL connection string in an init file somewhere.

What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It is a system that monitors thousands of sensors.   I know SQL uses TCP IP, shared and named to its connection but I am clueless if the monitor system was also able to connect via SNMP directly or if there is some port to connects to it.

Comment: I have no idea what your mental model of this is. The monitoring system uses SNMP, a protocol, to gather data from what it monitors, and then it also connects to a SQL server (thus making it a SQL client), using a SQL connection that is a different protocol, to store the data. It does not use the SNMP protocol to connect to the SQL server because that's not how any of this works.

What actual problem are you trying to solve?